# SCP giving out a blank line and not transfering files

Tags: scp

As said, an image is worth a thousand words:

[image]

This blank line is weird.

SSH works correctly.

Some verbose mode shows me this:

[image]

I just... scp never gave up on me. Looks like it did today.

Comment: I wanted to add the [tag:wtf] tag, but don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Totally worth that tag!

Comment: Could the line be the progress meter? I know it is normally `===>` but...

Comment: @terdon yeah, this is normally `===>`. Maybe it's a "starting to write but failed" line... dunno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I added some fun stuff in the remote .bashrc, namely some cowsay + fortune.

This screwed everything up. Removing it, everything worked flawlessly again.

Answer (score 1):

For those stumbling on this thread as I did, but who want to preserve their fortune telling cow friends - Add this to the head of your `.bashrc`.

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything                                                                                                
# prevents bashrc from breaking non-interactive commands                                                                                             
# like SCP                                                                                                                                       
case $- in                                                                                                                                       
    *i*) ;;                                                                                                                                      
    *) return;;                                                                                                                                  
esac
```

This will check for interactivity and not run your `.bashrc` for non-interactive shells - such as the SCP case above.

Answer (score 0):

"Note that scp clients do not know how to handle certain URI characters - therefore the filename reported in the status is mangled to remove bad characters with "_" (underscores). This is only for the status report and has no affect on the target filename."

[From this page](http://docs.netkernel.org/book/view/book:ssh:transport:book/doc:ssh:transport:scp) (I googled "scp sink underscore" and looked at the first link. Others may be more explicit)

You may want to try another LC_LANG : `LC_LANG=C scp ..........` (and try others, until display is correctly showing the filename).